# Regex to find all numbers followed by dot

Tags: php, regex

I need regex that will escape `.` coming right after number.

`1. Something` -> `1\. Something`

This will be used to avoid markdown formatting this line as ordered list.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What about `12.34`?

Comment: @toto `12.34` -> `12\.34`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any digit - `\d`
any count - `+`
dot - `\.`

more explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/oe5Etz/1)
and [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) docs

so it might be smth like that

```
<?php

$string = '1. Something 2. Something 3.Something';
$pattern = '/(\d+)\./';
$replacement = '${1}\.';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: This is working great, do you know how to replace it with two slashes `\\` ?

Comment: just add a slash:) '${1}\\.';

Comment: I get same result. It has something to do with escaping. To get two slashes you need to use `'${1}\\\\\.'`.

Comment: yeap, my bad - the doc says `To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled ("\\\\" PHP string). `

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following code and is working as per your requirement

```
$re = '/([0-9]+)\s*(\.\s*)/m';
$str = '1. 2. 3.
1. text1 1.text  1 . test
1.next line';

$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```